# How to correctly split Node js code with queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in app js:

```
const express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
const app = express();
var Test = require('./test')()
```

in Test.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

module.exports = function Test(){
    console.log('#before'); // work

    app.get('/test', (req, res)=>{ //not work
        console.log(('#after'));
    })
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
require('./test')(app)
```

test.js

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
        );
        next()
    })

    app.get('/test', (req, res)=>{
        console.log(('#after'));
        res.send('sup')
    })
}
```